# Use for ActionListenerWrapper in jsf

Tags: java, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

ActionListenerWrapper was introduced in jsf 2.2 and am wondering why wrapping an ActionListener interface within a ActionListenerWrapper in jsf when you can just implement the ActionListener and user it without the wrapper?.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the information available for `ActionListenerWrapper`

> Provides a simple implementation of ActionListener that can be
>   subclassed by developers wishing to provide specialized behavior to an
>   existing ActionListener instance. The default implementation of all
>   methods is to call through to the wrapped ActionListener.

How to use

> Usage: extend this class and override getWrapped() to return the
>   instance we are wrapping.

So with the help of `ActionListenerWrapper` you can make the change in existing ActionListener.

For more information you can check [ActionListenerWrapper is missing](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-993)